# CSS selector won't select custom boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, css

So I ran into a weird problem that doesn't make sense to me. I'm trying to select an html element with the the boolean attribute `data-project-next`. Here is the line of the element that I'm trying to select and the line of JavaScript to select element, but I keep getting an undefined value, even when I try it in the browser console:

```js
let nextBtnLink = document.querySelector("a[data-next-project]");
console.log(nextBtnLink);
```

```html
<a class="ajax-page-load" data-next-project><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

I've checked the documentation and what I'm doing seems to be correct so I'm not sure why this selector is not working. I will mention I am loading this section of the page with Asynchronously with JavaScript, but again even after the html has been loaded into the DOM and I run the function in the console, it still returns nothing.

Any thoughts on my syntax, or if I'm selecting this element wrong.

Comment: works just fine

Comment: I've added your code to a Stack Snippet, and you can see that the element is being found successfully.

Comment: Are you sure `console.log` is printing undefined? `console.log` _returns_ undefined, which you would see in most browser consoles. I'm using google chrome and with your code I see it log the element, and return undefined.

Comment: `document.querySelector` ***cannot*** return `undefined`! If it doesn't find the element, returns `null`. The problem probably comes from elsewhere

Comment: @FZs, That gave me enough to go off of. I guess I had been debugging from further down my code. somewhere the code changes it to undefined. thank you !!!!